# Firebase Storage Rule to Disallow Overwrite

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

I don't want user to be able upload a new file which is already exist with the same name in storage,

Here is what I've tried but still getting `403` when I upload a nonexist file.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/projectid/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if !resource || request.resource.name == resource.name;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was at the same situation and i changed the file name using the uid+timestamp.png at the client side

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I want to make my storage public but not allow anyone to overwrite any file.. In your situation you may have an auth rule.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40747704/4063532 as i said

Comment: nope, it's not working either.

Comment: sorry i have no other ideas but you can contact the firebase support they can help you