# Equivalent of .push in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to convert my firebase implementation which previously used realtime database to use firestore as I like the idea of collections and the perks of using it.

How do I implement below into firestore equivalent?

```
firebase.database().ref('documentPath').push()
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To have the same bahaviour in Cloud Firestore as you have in Firebase Realtime database when using the `push()` function, is to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you. You can do this by calling `add()` function like this:

```
var addYourDoc = db.collection('documentPath').add({
  property_key: 'property_value',
}).then(ref => {
  console.log('document ID: ', ref.id);
});
```

The output in the console will be the actual generated id.

Comment: it did. I actually only have to just set the path then add the property then firebase will handle it for me.