# Adding image in Firebase Storage and its reference in Firestore, while avoiding double write in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to add an Image (of a user generated post) in Firebase Storage, and its url in the Firestore DB. But there can be a lot of images, so i want to keep them in folders in Storage.

So the storage path looks like this:

```
/${uid}/posts/${postId}/${image1.name}
```

Here the `postId` is the document reference Id of a new Post that i add in Firestore.
But since firestore does not support empty doc using the `.add()` api, I have to a dummy write op, just to get the doc ref Id (which is postId)

```
db.collection('posts').add({isExist: true})
.then(docRef => { postDocRef = docRef; postId = docRef.id } )
```

Now i use this `postId` in the storage path, and upload the image.

Once the upload is done, I receive its download url (`getDownloadURL()`), which i want to store in the Firestore DB. So i had to trigger another write to the same doc and update it with the image download url.

```
postDocRef.update({ url : storageDownloadUrl })
```

This whole process causes two write ops to the Firestore.

Is there a better way that can result in single write to Firestore.

Few option that i thought:

1. Generate postId locally on my own, that will act as document Id as
   well. [[Does Firebase storage offer unique Id's for files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747603/does-firebase-storage-offer-unique-ids-for-files][1])
2. Do not use postId in the storage path, instead generate unique
   image.name
3. Firestore considers providing reference to empty docs, like in realtime DB [[Equivalent of .push in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923211/equivalent-of-push-in-firestore][1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a "dummy write" to get a unique generated document ID.  You can simply use the [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method *with no parameters* to generate a DocumentReference with a unique id, then use that to write the entire document some time later when the data is ready.  Those unique IDs are always generated synchronously on the client.

Comment: Is it safe? even if the app is offline?

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic, it might help somewhere:

```
final Uri uri = data.getData();
//From the onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method

StorageReference storageReference = YOUR_PAPER_STORAGE_REF;

// Create the file metadata
StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
    .setContentType("application/pdf").build();

storageReference.putFile(uri, metadata)
.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    // Forward any exceptions
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                    }

                    // Request the public download URL
                    return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            })
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull Uri downloadUri) {

                    PaperPost mPaperPost = new PaperPost(mFirebaseUser, downloadUri.toString());

                    final DocumentReference mPPPostRef = mFirestore.collection("tblPapers").document().set(mPaperPost);
                }
            })
```